# Session lost when switching language on Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, autologin

I am developing an intranet with Joomla 2.5 and I have two menu type modules, one for each language (English and Spanish). The type of access for both menu items registered user is of type (pre-installed by default in Joomla).

I have activated the module language change and the auto-login plugin (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/10508).

When I access the website through the auto-login (I access directly in English) I can navigate successfully through all the menu items. The problem is when language change. Changing the language session is lost and I get the screen with the login form.

Why session is lost?, What is the problem?.

Thanks for the help.

Greetings!

Comment: You may want to try joomfish. http://www.joomfish.net/

Comment: As far as possible, I would avoid using Joomfish. Thank you.

Comment: what is the url when you change language? (the browser should show it when you put hand cursor over the link)

Comment: @Caner The URL to which the link points to language change is that which corresponds to the page in another language (the pages are linked from the manager of Joomla.). That is, if I'm on a page with url "index.php/en/gallery", the link to change language is "index.php/es/pagina-galeria"

Comment: Try to disable the autlogin plugin to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the core of Joomla. The problem was in a module (which I developed myself) and made ​​a `session_destroy()`. In addition, this module was assigned to all menu items in Spanish.

I feel have made you waste time. Apologies.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this might help:

On backend go to `site->global->congiguration->system->session settings` and try playing with options there.